# Android Studio: Nothing is showing up on my preview xml page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Whenever I go to the design tab of an XML file, the preview is completely blank.  Even when I try to put components it does not visually show up.  Below is a link to an example.

I tried to resync with Gradle files, invalidate catches and restart and even reinstalled Android Studios, but nothing works.

What should I do?

[image: Totally blank preview]

Edit: Somehow by changing the api values next to AppTheme on top it works.  But it leads to another problem: none of the attributes are showing up.  Is there another fix to this? I tried another invalidate and restart with no success.

[Attribute side is completely blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlsBp.png)

Comment: lower your comileSdkversion and targetSdkVersion reBuild and check

Comment: when you create a demo project without touching the code, is it still blank?

Comment: Yes, it's completely blank.

Comment: if you are using android studio 3.0 and higher.  change your style.xml AppTheme from **`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`** to **`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`**

Comment: Hmm... @ChethanKumar I don't think you're supposed to inherit from `Base.*` themes.

Comment: lower the sdk version. You can se it in the image. There is a dripdown. It shows 28 . Lower it. it should work

Answer (score 1):

if you are using build gradle version 28,

in build.gradle file  depencies using "28.0.0"

just change it to

28.0.0-alpha1

it wil solve the problem hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Please check if in your project is using any support library that is `RC` or `beta`. **If you are using an RC or beta, try a downgrade.**

Another thing you could try is to downgrade also your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` and rebuild your project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @WannaInternet does this answer fix your issue?

Comment: Hey Andre, pretty much.  The explanation Rohit gave in the comment section was the the key.  All I did was lower the sdk version number next to the "AppTheme" area and it worked like a charm.  But then ,the attributes didn't show up.  If that happens, you have to uninstall AS and delete C:/Users/xxx/.gradle and C:/Users/xxx/.AndroidStudiox.x files and reinstall AS.  The uninstaller somehow leaves that out.  That did the trick. Thank you, both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Just go to styles.xml and change this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the theme you have selected is right or not. In my case i solved the issue by changing the theme by noactionbar that I have used in menifest for this activity.

Comment: I fixed that problem.  Please take a look at my edit.  My attributes aren't showing.

Comment: try to downgrade your api level 28 to 27 and check.